# Telerik radGrid - possible to do use AllowAutomaticUpdates when Datasource = a dataset?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik, radgrid

I am setting the datasource of my radGrid to a dataset (that I have stored in session).
I have enabled  AllowAutomaticUpdates and EnableViewState, implemented NeedDataSource, set DatakeyNames, etc. (see code below)

However, when I press the Edit button and make a change and press the Update link, the record does not update and leave Edit Mode.....it just stays in edit mode, and no error of any kind occurs.

So, the question is....does anyone know if radGrid with EnableViewstate even supports AutomaticUpdates, so the changes in the grid will be automatically pushed into the dataset to which it is bound?

One would think you could read the documentation, but I have been unable to find a definitive answer.

Thanks

---

```
<telerik:Radgrid id="grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" 
            AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" GridLines="None" >

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim data As New DataGateway
            Dim ds As DataSet = data.GetEmployeesByProgram(Year:=2009, ProgramName:="Long Term Incentive Stock Program")
            Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
            ds.Tables(0).PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns("EmployeeNum"), dt.Columns("ProgramName"), dt.Columns("Year")}
            Session("datasource") = ds
            With Me.grid
                .AllowAutomaticUpdates = True
                .AutoGenerateColumns = True
                .AllowSorting = True
                .AutoGenerateEditColumn = True
                .EnableViewState = True     'IS REQUIRED!!!
                Me.grid.MasterTableView.AllowAutomaticUpdates = True
                Me.grid.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.InPlace
            End With
        End If
    End Sub




Private Sub grid_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles grid.NeedDataSource
        Debug.WriteLine("NeedDataSource: " & e.RebindReason.ToString)
        Dim ds As DataSet = CType(Session("datasource"), DataSet)
        Me.grid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = New String() {"EmployeeNum", "ProgramName", "Year"}
        Me.grid.DataSource = ds

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, there is one key issue at play here:

The "automatic" operations are only supported when you're using a Data Source control to bind the grid. That *includes* the ObjectDataSource, so you can use your DAL with the ODS and then support auto upserts/updates/deletes.

When binding directly to a data table, you must handle the updates manually. That's because it is the data source controls- not the RadGrid- that are providing the "auto" logic for CRUD operations. Fortunately, it's not hard to handle update manually if that's the path you prefer. Check out some of the demos on Telerik.com for examples:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/editmodes/defaultcs.aspx

You can also use the RadGrid with ViewState disabled if you want to. The best way to do that is to use the Grid's support for client-side databinding (though that does require that you expose your DAL via a Service Layer). Check out the demos for that approach here:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/insertupdatedelete/defaultcs.aspx

Hope that helps!
-Todd

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been answered in the Telerik forums:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/is-it-possible-to-do-automaticupdates-to-a-dataset.aspx

Comment: This is way old at this point in time, but it's worth noting that link is dead now.