# RadGrid update object used for DataSource on edit automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

In essence my question boils down to this: [Telerik radGrid - possible to do use AllowAutomaticUpdates when Datasource = a dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488039/telerik-radgrid-possible-to-do-use-allowautomaticupdates-when-datasource-a-d)

Except with a few key differences.

1. I'm looking to update my Session-stored object as soon as an InPlace edit is done.  This means no EditColumn or update buttons. (User types in value, hits tab or clicks away etc, then save that)
2. I'm using an LLBLGen EntityBase2 type as the RadGrid's DataSource, which I am binding in code-behind.  (Can this be auto-updated with AllowAutomaticUpdate?)
3. The question referenced is 7 years old, has anything major changed since then that might improve this process?

I can compromise on having no update or save buttons.  In that case I still need to update my Session-stored EntityBase2 object manually, I think, which wouldn't be too bad if what I'm trying to do is just too complex.

But the question stands, can I achieve automatic update from the grid immediately after an edit, and to the DataSource's object?